# ReactJs: Как [следует] глобально отслеживать изменение состояния компонентов?

Tags: reactjs

Прошу быть снисходительными, ибо я дилетант. 
**Ситуация:** При рендере компонента1 используется компонент2 в который передается свойство. Состояние компонента2 меняется в его обработчике. Нужно зафиксировать изменение состояния компонента2 и учесть это в компоненте1.

```
var Component1 = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return{
      total: 0
    }
  },
  render(){
    const total = this.state.total;
    return <Component2 total={total} />
  }
});

var Component2 = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return{
      total: this.props.total
    }
  },
  handleClick(){
    var total = this.state.total + 1;
    this.setState({total: total});
  },
  render(){
    const total = this.state.total;
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>{total}</div>
  }
});
```

- **Вопрос1:** Как изменить состояние total в Component1 из Component2?
- **Вопрос2:** (на случай, если первый вариант совсем абсурдный): какой
  вариант вы бы предложили для учета изменений состояния другого
  компонента (нужно ли для этого передавать свойство в компонетны по
  цепочке - если да, как получить обратную связь)?

Comment: Перефразирую: Мне нужно передавать свойство в компонент2, мненять глобальную переменную из компонента2 и инициализировать измененное значение в компоненте1. Я на правильном пути?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У второго компонента не должно быть `state`. Один из вариантов - передавать обработчик.

```js
var Component1 = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      total: 0
    }
  },
  render(){
    var total = this.state.total;
    return React.createElement(Component2, {
      total: this.state.total,
      updateTotal: this.updateTotal
    });
  },
  updateTotal(total) {
    this.setState({total: total});
  }
});

var Component2 = React.createClass({
  handleClick() {
    this.props.updateTotal(this.props.total + 1);
  },
  render() {
    return React.DOM.div({onClick: this.handleClick}, this.props.total);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Component1, null),
  document.querySelector('main')
);
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 7em;
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.2.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Comment: Дорисуйте, пожалуйста, 3-компонентную схему с изменением total. Если несложно.

Comment: @pravosleva В вопросе нет трёх компонентов. Я не понял, что требуется сделать.

Comment: @ Qwertiy Я хотел просмотреть на реализацию передачи такого обработчика третьему элементу (Comp3) через посредника (Comp2). Причина: Comp2 слишком сложный - хочу его разбить еще. Резюмирую: Вы объявили обработчик в Comp1, передали его в Comp2, далее проект усложняется: в Comp2 появился Comp3 >> обработчик должен быть передан в Comp3. Как будет выглядеть посредник (Comp2)?

Comment: @ Qwertiy На вопрос с двумя компонентами Вы ответили исчерпывающе (кстати, спасибо!). Насчет третьего - это уже усложненный вариант задачи.

Comment: Вопрос снят, спасибо! Решил придерживаться двух компонентов... По-моему, это лучше влияет на читабельность кода.

Comment: @pravosleva, просто передать из третьего обработчик во второй, а оттуда прокинуть в первый. Ну или подумать про что-нибудь типа flux/redux.